# Canvas rectangel moody border

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

When drawing a rectangle in the canvas I'm getting a moody fading out border I want it to be sharp, how?

```
    ctx.fillStyle = "#CF0"
    ctx.fillRect(0,0,20,20)
```

Comment: Can you provide sample code, as well as sample output? Through a JSFiddle perhaps?

Comment: Might be because of canvas's anti-aliasing.  Is your border better if you do this: ctx.fillRect(0.5,0.5,20.5,20.5)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In canvas there are two different and independent sizes:

- the size on the screen (`.offsetWidth` and `.offsetHeight`)
- the size in pixels (`.width` and `.height`)

If the two are not identical your graphics will look inaccurate (more specifically blurry if the size in pixels is smaller).

In some cases (e.g. Apple "retina" displays) you need to have the size in pixels exactly twice the size on screen to get accurate rendering.